Spring-Loaded Link/Joint in Robot URDF
I'd like to make a link/joint spring-loaded in my URDF, so that it takes a certain level of force to displace it and so that it returns to a base/equilibrium position when not in contact with anything.
I know this can be done using Gazebo elements, e.g.
<gazebo reference="Joint">
    <implicitSpringDamper>true</implicitSpringDamper>
    <springStiffness>50</springStiffness>
    <springReference>0.8</springReference>
</gazebo>

However, I'd like to use this URDF in PyBullet/MuJoCo/Isaac environments.
Is it possible to achieve this somehow? Thanks for any help.
